# Merging two scripts

Tags: python, function, import

I have two scripts that individually run fine[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774166/recording-audio-from-usb-with-pyaudio) and I want to merge them into one.

The end goal here is to collect 360 sound samples. One for each degree of movement on a motor. And save each of them with its name, serial, and position.

Whats the best way to do this while sharing some variables like "degree" which vary from 0 to 360, and "mic_name", "mic_sn" which are user inputed once at the beginning?

Mic_Characterization.py

```
import serial
import time


def main():
 degree = 0
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A906OZ7G', baudrate=9600,  timeout=1)
 time.sleep(1)
 ser.write(b"MA 0\r")
 time.sleep(2.5)


 while degree < 360:
    print("Sound file Captured at Position = " + str(degree) + "°")
    ser.write(b"MR 5120\r")
    time.sleep(2)
    degree += 1

else:
    ser.write(b"MA 0\r")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print("Characterization Complete")
    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Audio_Collection.py

```
def audio():
 mic_name = input(str("Type Microphone Model: "))
 mic_sn = input(str("Type Microphone Serial Number: "))
 degree = 0
 CHUNK = 1024
 FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
 CHANNELS = 2
 RATE = 44100
 RECORD_SECONDS = 5
 WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "" + mic_name + "_" + mic_sn + "_at_" + str(degree) + "_degrees.wav"
 p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

 stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                input_device_index=2)

 print("* recording")

 frames = []

 for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

 print("* done recording")

 stream.stop_stream()
 stream.close()
 p.terminate()

 wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
 wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
 wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
 wf.setframerate(RATE)
 wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
 wf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by naming the function for my second program:

`def audio(mic_name, mic_sn, degree=0):`

and adding this to the end of that script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 mic_name = input(str("Type Microphone Model: "))
 mic_sn = input(str("Type Microphone Serial Number: "))
 audio(mic_name, mic_sn)
```

Then on the main script I added:

```
import Audio_Collection

def main():
  mic_name = input(str("Type Microphone Model: "))
  mic_sn = input(str("Type Microphone Serial Number: "))
```

and finally in the loop added:

```
Audio_Collection.audio(mic_name, mic_sn, degree)
```